# Showing that $\cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x) = \frac12 \cos(2x)\;(\cos(4x)+\cos(2x))$

Tags: trigonometry

> Why does the following hold? 
>   $$\cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x) = \frac12 \cos(2x)\;(\cos(4x)+\cos(2x))$$

On finding the nth differential coefficient for $$\cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x)$$ , they covert $$\cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x)$$ to $$\frac12 \cos(2x)\;(\cos(4x)+\cos(2x))$$ as a first step.

But i can't understand how they can do that.

Please tell me the steps (or) intuition behind it ? Thanks! :)

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3392852/edit) to include what you know about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information will help answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know or using techniques with which you aren't familiar. (You *do* realize that there's a factor of $\cos 2x$ on both sides, right? This reduces the difficulty of the problem a bit.)

Comment: @Blue I have added some information. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use $\cos A+\cos B=2\cos (\frac{A+B}{2})\cos (\frac{A-B}{2})$

$RHS=\frac12 \cos(2x)\;(\cos(4x)+\cos(2x))$

$=\frac12 \cos(2x)\;2\cos(\frac{4x+2x}{2})\cos (\frac{4x-2x}{2})$

$=\cos(2x)\;\cos3x\cos x$

$=LHS$

Comment: Thank you so much!